# Cannot read properties undefined (reading 'send')

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('723180986899246090').send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('723180986899246090').send(`${member} has left the server.`);
});

    client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Welcome to the server!')
            .setDescription(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`)
            .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .addFields(
                { name: 'User:', value: `${member.user.tag}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'ID:', value: `${member.user.id}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Joined at:', value: `${member.joinedAt}`, inline: true },
            )   
            })
```

I've been working on user welcome message using embed, but when first try it said "Cannot read properties undefined  (reading 'send')"

But if I remove client.on('guildMemberAdd and guildMemberRemove') and change it with

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === config.welcomeChannel);
    if (!channel) return;
    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
});
```

it work (bot will ping new members but only send regular message and not embedded) any solution ? I'm kinda new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things, first you want to put all of your code that happens when a member joins, under the same event, you don't want multiple lines of `client.on('guildMemberAdd'`

With that said I am assuming you are on discord v13 but I'll give examples for v12 as well

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === config.welcomeChannel);

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Welcome to the server!')
        .setDescription(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`)
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .addFields({
            name: 'User:',
            value: `${member.user.tag}`,
            inline: true
        }, {
            name: 'ID:',
            value: `${member.user.id}`,
            inline: true
        }, {
            name: 'Joined at:',
            value: `${member.joinedAt}`,
            inline: true
        })


// if using v13

        channel.send({
            embeds: [embed]
        })

// if using v12

        channel.send(embed)
})
```